# How to Drag and Drop multiple table cells in same table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop multiple cells from a table, but the code which I am referring to is limited to a single cell operations. But I want to perform the same operation for multiple cells. Code am using is below:

```css
table th,table td{
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;

}
table span{
    display:block;
    background-color: #09C;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="#our_table"  border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>head1</th>
        <th>head1</th>
        <th>head1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">aaa</span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.event').on("dragstart", function (event) {
        var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.type === 'drop') {
            var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
            de = $('#'+data).detach();
            de.appendTo($(this));   
        };
    });
})
```

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/egt4U/).

Comment: For drag and drop multiple cells wouldn't assigning "event" class to other cells solve this?

Comment: Can you show some animation or something what exact behavior you want?